# How can I search a specific element on the page for text using XPATH (Selenium);

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I can't seem to find an example of this.

What I am trying to do is search a specific div element on the page for text that has the potential to change.

So it'd be like this

```
<div id="coolId">
   <div>This</div>
   <div>Can</div>
   <div>Change depending on the iteration of the page</div>
</div>
```

In my case, the div **coolID** will always be present, but the text within it's *inner* divs and child elements will change depending on which iteration of the page is loaded, and I need to search for the presence of certain terms within this coolID div and cool div only because I know it will always be there, and I'd like to specify the search as much as possible so as not to potentially contaminate results with other text from other places on the page.

In my head, I sort of see it like this (using the above example):

```
"//div[@id='coolId', contains(text(), 'Change depending on the iteration of the page')]"
```

Or something to this effect.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
div_element_with_needed_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='coolId']/div[text()[contains(.,'Change depending on the iteration of the page')]]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure you can set a correct XPath based on all 3 inner elements texts.
What you clearly can is to locate the outer `div` with `id = coolId` based on one of the inner texts that will be unique and then to extract all the inner texts form it.

```py
the_total_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id and contains(.,'Change depending on the iteration of the page')]").text
```

This will give you

```py
the_total_text = This Can Change depending on the iteration of the page
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML:

```
<div id="coolId">
   <div>This</div>
   <div>Can</div>
   <div>Change depending on the iteration of the page</div>
</div>
```

to retrieve the variable texts with respective to the parent *`<div id="coolId">`* you can use the following solutions:

- Extracting *This* using *xpath*:

  ```
  first_child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='coolId']//following::div[1]").text
  ```
- Extracting *Can* using *xpath*:

  ```
  second_child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='coolId']//following::div[2]").text
  ```
- Extracting *Change depending on the iteration of the page* using *xpath*:

  ```
  third_child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='coolId']//following::div[3]").text
  ```

To extract all the texts from the decendents using *xpath*:

```
  all_child_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='coolId']").text
```